# No route matches in Rspec Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I'm using Rails 4.1 and I have an API json, but doesn't work on Rspec-Rails.

rspec-rails - Version used 3.2.1

$ rake routes

```
GET  /cities/:code(.:format)     cities#show
```

cities_controller.rb

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def show
    code = params[:code]
    respond_with City.find_by_code(code)
  end
end
```

cities_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CitiesController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET city" do
    it "should be ok" do
      get '/cities', :code => 'DUB', :format => :json
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

When I execute rspec, I receive this

```
Failure/Error: data = get '/cities', :code => 'DUB', :format => :json
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/cities", :controller=>"cities", :code=>"DUB", :format=>:json}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
get :show, :code => 'DUB', :format => :json
```

The `get` method accepts the name of the controller action, not a path. See [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-get) for more information.

Comment: Thanks fivedigit, same error about No route matches  {:action=>"/cities", :controller=>"cities", :code=>"DUB", :format=>:json}

Comment: I hadn't noticed this when I answered, but I thought your action was actually called `cities` instead of show. Updating my answer.